# Merging two rows in mvc using drag and drop functionality

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to use drag and drop functionality. I have to merge two rows of a table when I drag one row onto another in **ASP.NET MVC 5**.

I have a table say `Table1`:

[image]

I want to add a functionality such that when I drag a row over another row, the contents of the two rows are merged and a new row is generated containing the new content i.e. the merged contents of the rows and the child rows are removed.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please add more details.

Comment: I have a table showing records like:

Comment: Can u understand the question now

Comment: ur img is not visible. plz ask your question clearly

Comment: How would you *merge* those rows `act52` and `act53` together? Define the behavior!

Comment: Its just a table with 4 fields Activity text,deliverable,name,activity type. I want  to be able to merge two rows of the table when I drag one row onto another.

Comment: All the contents are merged like: if I merge first and second row the contents become ActivityText becomes Act44act52  ,  Deliverables becomes 111111111112222222222222222222222222222,    Name becomeProject2Project2 . This is the required behavior that the contents of all the fields are merged

Comment: Anyone????? A let help would be nice....

Comment: I'm curious what happens to data behind-the scenes: is it stored in some property, or is it display-only?

Comment: The data behind is also merged

Comment: Please a little help would be nice

Comment: Anyone I am still stuck....................